# is it possible to somehow get an IP address or hostname from a symbolic link? (windows 7)

Tags: winapi, symlink

I am working with a product that has symbolic links used with it. The problem is, I have to somehow get the IP address (or hostname) to which the symlink refers in order pass the server name in to connect to a socket-based WCF service on a different host. This service runs on multiple hosts.

I know that if it is possible it will be in Win32 C layer.

BTW, I am working with Windows 7.

If it is not possible, I will have to go to a meta-data solution; but I would like to know if it is feasible.

Thank you,
Bill Shurtleff

Answer (score 0):

The real question is not how to retrieve an IP/hostname from a symbolic link (symlinks usually refer to local filesystem objects, but can also refer to UNCs), but really how to retrieve the target of the link in general.  And that is answered in Raymond Chen's blog:

[How do I get information about the target of a symbolic link?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/02/12/9962359.aspx)

> Functions like `GetFileAttributes` and `FindFirstFile`, when asked to provide information about a symbolic link, returns information about the link itself and not the link destination. If you use the `FindFirstFile` function, you can tell that you have a symbolic link because the file attributes will have the `FILE_ATTRIBUTES_REPARSE_POINT` flag set, and the `dwReserved0` member will contain the special value `IO_REPARSE_TAG_SYMLINK`.
>
> Okay, great, so now I know I have a symbolic link, but what if I want information about the link target? For example, I want to know the size of the link target, its last-modified time, and its name.
>
> **To do this, you open the symbolic link. The I/O manager dereferences the symbolic link and gives you a handle to the link destination. You can then call functions like `GetFileSize`, `GetFileInformationByHandleEx`, or `GetFinalPathNameByHandle` to obtain information about the symbolic link target**.

So, you have to actually open the target of the link, then you can query the opened handle for the file path that it refers to.  Then you can parse out the IP/hostname from that path as needed.

Alternatively, as mentioned in comments on that same page:

> You can also use DeviceIoControl with FSCTL_GET_REPARSE_POINT to obtain information about the symbolic link target "as is".

But you still have to open the link in order to pass its handle to `DeviceIoControl()`.